# Ignore a particular param from Ransack search but stay in search form

Tags: ransack

On my Ransack search form, I have a field called created_at_between which is a date range you can see from the screenshot below. I don't want Ransack to directly use it. I want to ignore this from the search instead but I still need it for the search form in the date range field to display the value after the form is submitted. That way, the user knows which date range he used for the search.

So, if I do this, params[:q].except("created_at_between"), it correctly ignores the param and the search result comes ok. But I think I lose it from the @q variable and so it does not show up in the search form date field after submitting.

Search form:

[image]

Code in the controller:

```
@q = Productivity.accessible_by(current_ability, :read)

    if params[:q][:created_at_between]
      date = date_range_separator(params[:q][:created_at_between])
      @q = @q.where('lower(duration) >= ? ', date[:date_from])
             .where('upper(duration) <= ? ', date[:date_to])
    end
    s_param = params[:q].except("created_at_between")
    @q = @q.ransack(s_param)

    @productivities = @q.result
                        .order('created_at DESC')
                        .page(params[:page])
```